# Upgrading MOSS 2007

Tags: 2007, upgrade

My MOSS 2007 version is 12.0.0.6421 and I want to upgrade it to 12.0.0.6548.

But between these two versions there are many other versions too.

Can I directly upgrade to 12.0.0.6548 or should I install the all the remaining versions
then 12.0.0.6548?

Answer (score 3):

You are currently at Service Pack 2, which is good. The Cumulative Updates address issues that you may have experienced. You should only apply the Cumulative Updates in production if you are experiencing the issue that the CU addresses. That said, the CUs do contain previous CUs, so if you want to apply only the most recent, you will recieve the fixes in the prior ones.

Comment: Great reference of version numbers - http://todd-carter.com/page/SharePointVersions.aspx